# Good way to implement a child class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

So I have about 10-15 classes (this could grow to a much larger number in time) and they all have fairly similar variables within them:

```
temp
conditions
humidity
load
```

..And stuff like that.   I'm looking to implement a parent class (abstract) to better manage this since they are all runnable.

There's a part where I call a constructor for each of them and it's... just bad.

```
 public ThreadHandler(NH.NHandler NSH, int threadNum){
    this.threadNum=threadNum;
    this.NSH = NSH;
}

public ThreadHandler(OPA.OpaHandler SgeSH, int threadNum){
    this.threadNum=threadNum;
    this.OpaSH = OpaSH;
}

public ThreadHandler(SGE.SgeHandler SgeSH, int threadNum){
    this.threadNum=threadNum;
    this.SgeSH = SgeSH;
}
```

..... and on for 15

How would I implement a parent class to simply do

```
public ThreadHandler(objectType name, int threadNum){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to explain your problem better.  What are these classes that are parms to your constructor?  Are they all subclasses of some common superclass?

Comment: That's what I'm looking to make so I can just use a common instructor.

They all have very similar data in them, so a parent class with some variables makes sense.   Essentilly I'm trying to make the constructor in ThreadHandler handle any of my types automatically, rather than having 15 different constructors.  It'll make the code easier to read / understand, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: You didn't exactly answer my question.  (Keep in mind that you can implement a constructor for each subclass, to set the fields specific to that subclass.  You could also use a generic/template implementation, but I suspect that's above your pay grade at present.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an interface, say, IHandler with common methods and all handlers should implement this interface

```
public interface IHandler {
      .... declare public methods 
    }
```

```
public NHandler implements IHandler  {
       .... implement all the methods declared in IHandler..
    }
```

Now you can just have the following in `ThreadHandler`

```
public ThreadHandler(IHandler  handler, int threadNum){
        .... call the methods
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, assuming that your ThreadHandler class can treat all 10-15 of your classes the same way. It would also be a good idea to create an AbstractHandler class that contained the shared fields common to each IHandler implementation, namely temp, conditions, humidity, load, etc. Then each of your 10-15 classes need not duplicate these fields and their related logic (validation, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I have another example using `abstract class` and `extends` that to `ChildClass`. I hope will help your problem.

**ParentHandler.java**

```
public abstract ParentHandler<T> {

    public T obj;
    public int threadNum;
    // Declare the common variable here...

    public ParentHandler(T obj, int threadNum) {
        this.threadNum = threadNum;
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

**ChildHandler.java**

```
public class ChildHandler extends ParentHandler<NH.NHandler> {

    public ChildHandler(NH.NHandler nsh, int threadNum) {

        super(nsh, threadNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Implement an interface, every "child" class will implement it, then you can declare an object of the interface type and create a method that returns the especific class based on something, like this.

```
    public Interface ITest
    {
        string temp;
        void Test(string param1, string param2);
    }

    public Class Class1 : ITest
    {
        void Test(string param1, string param2)
        {
            // DO STUFF
        }
    }

    public Class Class2 : ITest
    {
        void Test(string param1, string param2)
        {
            // DO STUFF
        }
    }
```

And then:

```
    public ITest GetClass(string type)
    {
         switch (type)
         {
             case "class1":     
                   return new Class1();
             case "class2":     
                   return new Class2();
         }  
    }
```

And you call it like

```
    ITest obj = GetClass("class1");
    obj.Test();
```